# Typescript multiple object properties with shared types

Tags: typescript

After some typescript studying and asking around i come up with the following shared object types declaration for multiple properties.

- **Question 1: is there simplier way to do it for multiple props wih shared types?**
- **Question 2: how to resolve last two examples?**

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwArwPZgM5QF4oByZAQwFsJioAfE3AV3nKpvuIGMsAbLeYgChQkKADlGFAEYR4mHPiLEyqanRIALCIlQbgQwQHpDMRBTA9oIiMPDRT5y4SgBvKAG0A1hBBQUsBBQMbDwAXQAuKFxAtCgAXwBuQW5kaKgsKQArAEZIhwtoIhdBKFKoVghI4gBBVWR9ABoSsqYWSkqSGApEYA1iJrKobj54KvgIABMhOMEjQwB5MGBELHIeKGtbUUXl1bJ1oo9vX384JDR5MIB%20SOjz1HiklLSMzIAmSJ2VtediwYqqrUIPVprNjABhLDSFCTdJLb77DZ2LbQSHQ5Cww5eHx%20ZDiSQyOQhXChG7lAmyeJQABkUC%20ex4T1WLyyAGZImipDCJr9mqUASRqpYAB79PlQLQ6PSRN6CGZzKCXWSgJGiTgaMhoGzWAL3SEjZzoMjwZb7AA8ACUINx4BMzQBRYWcHiMCYQM0SaSyS64BokYb8YgAPj9yAp8CDNNcQ14-DJdyC8SDyWZwHSWQALHkYqh9fxeYMA6MSPBUFJQQqABJYADuGywUDIEx5mt8TYmPQR6zAxKgNZ6GigjGQnmQtbxx1wVxRUGqzc7DN%20Rx8txzESgUiwvAgmseKdSadeAFZPvDF7S5x3dj8inyi2My2Kyu2F2tIghGDZ5cYoNW68AGwgJ0XTdKAAE0oB7HAoAAM2wChG1VaAeEQbwNg0RApxnAANCDDmFVd7j9EBIjDL14D3Z5DyyAA2SJcILUoCJIMgpE4J9ShIqBsjlWYdWw5wrRtO1HWdV13Vwv1iBAYNQ3DZMqPTTIAHZ6Lw1w%20WY5Q2OmIA)

```
type StringProps = 'name' | 'surname' | 'color'
type NumberProps = 'age' | 'height'

//Simple type
type Simple = { [key in StringProps]: string };
const obj1: Simple = {
    name: 'Agent',
    surname: 'Smith',
    color: 'red'
}

//Optional type
type Optional = { [key in StringProps]?: string };
const obj2: Optional = {
    name: 'Agent'
}

//Combined optional type
type Combined = { [key in NumberProps]?: number } & Optional;
const obj3: Combined = {
    name: 'Alex',
    height: 2
}

// Property type change
type StringColor = Partial<Record<Exclude<NumberProps, 'color'>, number> & { color?: string }>
const obj4: StringColor = {
    color: 'rgb'
}

// How to add any additional props with unknown keys?
type Additional = { [key: string]: boolean };
const obj5: Optional & Additional = {
   color: 'rgb',
   additional: true
}

// How to exclude Y prop from a type like this?
type XY = { x: string, y: number };
const obj6: XY = {
   x: 'abc',
   y: 1
}

type X = Record<Exclude<XY, 'y'>, number>
const obj7: XY = {
   x: 'abc'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can clean this up a bit.

First make Records and then modify them, if you need the keys you can always call `keyof` on the type

```
type Simple = Record<'name' | 'surname' | 'color', string>
type Numbers = Record<'age' | 'height', number>

// if you need the keys
type SimpleKeys = keyof Simple // "name" | "surname" | "color"
type NumbersKeys = keyof Numbers // "age" | "height"

//Simple type
const obj1: Simple = {
    name: 'Agent',
    surname: 'Smith',
    color: 'red'
}

//Optional type
type Optional = Partial<Simple>
const obj2: Optional = {
    name: 'Agent'
}

//Combined optional type
type Combined = Partial<Numbers & Simple>;
const obj3: Combined = {
    name: 'Alex',
    height: 2
}

// Property type change
type StringColor = Partial<Omit<Simple, 'color'> & { color?: string }>
const obj4: StringColor = {
    color: 'rgb'
}

// How to exclude Y prop from a type like this?
type XY = { x: string, y: number };
// Pick<XY, 'x'> or Omit<XY, 'y'>
const obj6: Pick<XY, 'x'> = {
   x: 'abc',
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach for creating the types looks good to me.

As for question two, why not use [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) to exclude the property you are not interested in? e.g.

```
type X = Omit<XY, "y">
const obj7: X = {
   x: 'abc'
}
```

As for obj5:

```
type Any= { [key: string]: any};
const obj5: Any = {
   color: 'rgb',
   additional: true
}
```

Note how I didn't use "Optional & Any" as the use of "Any" would render the inclusion of "Optional" redundant.

Comment: thanks, but it's more about exluding few props from multiple property object

Comment: Just use `omit` then: `type X = Omit<XY, "y">`

Comment: @pascalpuetz thanks, now only  obj5 question left :)

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**:

The types look fine. You could switch it around by first creating the interfaces and then using `keyof`, but that is a matter of taste.

**Question 2**

*obj5*:

For `obj5`, you will most likely have to change the index signature of the object to `any`, as all declared, specific properties have to conform to the index signature.

```
type Additional = { [key: string]: any };
const obj5: Optional & Additional = {
   color: 'rgb',
   additional: true
}
```

Alternatively, you can handle this with a bit of typecasting, as you are allowed to declare this type. But you are not allowed to create it. Thus, you can typecast the created object to `any` and then back to the correct type like this:

```
type Additional = { [key: string]: boolean };
const obj5: Optional & Additional = {
   color: 'rgb',
   additional: true
} as any as Optional & Additional;
```

I gave a more detailed explanation on exactly this topic in another [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467454/6513723).

*obj6:*

For `obj6` you can simply use the `Omit` helper like this:

```
type XY = { x: string, y: number };
const obj6: XY = {
   x: 'abc',
   y: 1
}

type X = Omit<XY, "y">
const obj7: XY = {
   x: 'abc'
}
```

Comment: @RTW I added a Typesafe alternative for `obj5` solution.